# IIS7 hangs on requests while uploading file

Tags: iis, configuration, request

I am setting up a small ASP.net application on an IIS 7 server, but I have a small problem.
A part of the application is uploading large files using a simple upload form. The problem is that, when I start an upload and meanwhile try to continue using the application in another tab, the request just hangs. I guess there is some settings that does not allow concurrent requests from the same user, or something like that, but I have no idea where to look.

Does anyone know, how I can configure the server to allow for concurrent requests?

Answer (score 0):

@Sorenc Does it hang even when you wait for it to upload without trying to continue to use the app in another tab? When you say large files how large are they? There is a default upload limit in IIS 7 that from memory is about 28mb.

To change this load the configuration editor in IIS and go to System.webServer/security/authentication and change the value for request filtering. Numbers are in bytes, so 2200 000 000 is 2GB.

Now go to System.web/httpruntime and change the value there - 2097151 is 2GB.

Please note that the reason the upload size is what it is by default is for security reasons, so please proceed with caution if you think that this might be security problem.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question though, is it?

Answer (score 0):

ASP Apps tend to share a Session ID, and the session ID serializes access to the app by the same caller.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912995/asp-net-application-to-serve-multiple-requests-from-a-single-process

Avoid using Session state if you need to parallelize requests.